# Annoying white rounded rectangle follows cursor around after wrong keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, shortcut, cursor

After making the wrong keyboard shortcut, a weird rounded rectangle with a thick white border appeared around my cursor and followed the cursor around.

(I was trying to make the shortcut that arranges icons by kind)

Inside the rectangle the screen was almost normal but kind of pixelated. I couldn’t take a screenshot but I recreated in Illustrator:

[image]

It was extremely annoying and I had to log out of my session and back in to finish work.

What did I trigger and how do I get out of this horrible thing if it ever happens again?

macOS High Sierra

Comment: looks like zoom https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh35715/10.14/mac/10.14

Comment: Which one of these shortcuts is it? I tried to replicate and couldn't. It's on High Sierra

Comment: See System Preferences > Accessibility > zoom (or equivalent for High Sierra). Likely alt + command + B

Comment: @anki ok this was it (alt + command + 8). Weird that the ESC key cannot get you out of it! It’s not even a zoom, it just looks pixelated… make this an answer and I’ll accept it

Comment: Ah I didn't have my glasses on, it's 8 (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom in the sidebar.

Shortcut is <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh35715/10.14/mac/10.14

Comment: Actually, it happens when I click "CTRL" and "ALT" at the same time, which is preventing me from using an app's shortcut. Under Accessibility > Zoom, there was Zoom Style > Option and I had to untick toggle zoom with CTRL + ALT.